# I need to make samples. Can I use any product or fake products?

Tags: portfolio

I write animation software.  I need to demo it by making a bunch of examples and tutorials.  Can I use existing products, or are there fake products somewhere?

I've seen people use movie press items, is that legal?  For example, movies have press kits so their reviewers can use images from the movie in their reviews.  Can I use those when I make my samples?

Comment: Someone down voted this.. why?  Is this not a thing graphic artists face when they're looking to make a portfolio?

Comment: As far as I understand copyright you can use and reproduce other peoples work without permission if it is not for commercial purposes. If your portfolio is for jobs than it counts as self promotion and thus commercial. There are graphic "products" available on the web and places like deviant art and pinterest, just make sure you filter for "Free for use" and "no restrictions."

Comment: I can't be certain, but your question could have been downvoted because the community considers a good question to include what the asker has already tried to do to solve the problem on their own. What you're looking for are the rules regarding what is called "Fair Use". If you Google that term, you should find your answer. Good luck.

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear. You say you write animation *software*, and talk of demos; that implies you're creating a commercial product, which is an entirely different thing to a portfolio. You need to clarify exactly what you're creating and for what purpose. It's also not clear what you mean by "products"... how do "products" and/or movie press kits fit in to demos of your animation software?

Comment: @Cai Look at https://layerslider.kreaturamedia.com/sliders/  Layer Slider is animation software, and they have a 'portfolio' or 'demo' page (they call it 'sliders').  They use nike.  They use deadpool.  They're a commercial product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a legal advice.

I really do not understand the question. Products of what? Examples and tutorials on what? Cutscenes of what?

Well. There are sites where you can use some images with or without attribution, for example, freepik or pixabay. There are some sites where you can buy a royalty-free license.

You could find some mockups and use an invented brand. https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=mockups+free

The thing you are mentioning is an "editorial use" sometimes movies release material publicly so people comment on it.

What you can not do is infer in any way the product you are using is endorsing yours or your product is part of the workflow of a specific campaign.

---

Always read carefully the licenses on the resources you use, and make a text-log on the same folder you put your material.